# Problem with multiple FBX files imported into Unity

Tags: animation, import, .fbx

I imported into Blender a couple of FBX files from Mixamo.com. The problem is that both animation are one over the other. I want to have them more order to work with them and to use them in Unity. What am I missing?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Try importing it into Unity in this state. Unity should automatically take care of separating animations in the same Blender dope sheet, although I'm not certain.